# After installing 'World of Goo'...very bad things happened...help?

Tags: configuration, settings, data-loss

I have the DEB for 'World of Goo' and installed it in 11.04.
All seemed to be OK.

Started it...things got VERY strange !!!
It's intro started and everything else vanished 100% FULL screen, and neither KB nor mouse had any effects.

I am sad to admit that ultimately after trying any/every combo I could think of=> I pushed the power button. My bad - my VERY bad, it seems.

When I restarted the PC every bit of my stuff was gone, it was back to some strange default I hadn't seen before - my Firefox bookmarks are gone, my extensions are gone, many, many things are just...gone.

Can anyone please explain what may have happened and tell me if there is any road back short of reinstalling/re-creating everything ?
I know I should be creating back-ups and likely need to have something protecting these things like 'Back-In-Time' or the like, but, well - I wanted to play a bit and had no idea how bad this could possibly be !!!???

Thanks.

(Post-script)
Note to aspiring editors:
I have requested help with OS problems here and NOT with writing about them
Kindly ***only*** contribute useful/helpful info.
If you have a need to edit something please edit your own work as I am quite capable of editing my own ***if*** I consider it to be needed. Thanks.

Comment: This is the DEB from the official site !!!

Answer (score 0):

My current guess would be that the unclean shutdown of Linux causes file system corruption and in turn loss of some files. But only files currently opened/written should be affected, Firefox, Gnome or KDE settings would be obvious candidates, while other files should be fine. Which files exactly did you lose?

Some file systems are extremely susceptible to those problems, namely I had so much issues with XFS that I would recommend to stay the hell away from that. With other file systems I never had those issues, namely Ext3 always worked just fine even with regular system crashes. Ext4 had those issues early in development, but it should have been fixed since then and I didn't have issues with that either so far. Which file system are you using?

As for data recovery, there is no automatic system wide backup/undo/restore in Linux. However your Firefox bookmarks might still be fine, as Firefox keeps backups of them in:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/{PROFILE}/bookmarkbackups/
```